# R: return array index of partial string match

Tags: arrays, r, indexing, match

Suppose I have a 10x10 matrix populated by 1:100. I want to search for all the numbers ending in '0', and I want their `[i,j]` index numbers. I tried `which(..., arr.ind=T)`, but couldn't find a function that works with it. I also tried `grep('0$', ...)` but it only returns a single index of the matrix as a vector. I suppose it is possible to turn that number into a binary index, but is there a simpler way?

```
x <- t(matrix(1:100,nrow=10,ncol=10))
#  Output:
#  [1,]  1  10
#  [2,]  2  10
#  ...
#  [10,] 10 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the `grepl` output to a `matrix` with the same `dim` as the original 'x' and then use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE`.

```
which(`dim<-`(grepl('0$', x), dim(x)), arr.ind=TRUE)
#       row col
# [1,]   1  10
# [2,]   2  10
# [3,]   3  10
# [4,]   4  10
# [5,]   5  10
# [6,]   6  10
# [7,]   7  10
# [8,]   8  10
# [9,]   9  10
#[10,]  10  10
```

---

Or without changing the `dim`, we get the `grepl` output as a `logical` vector, negate (`!`) so that TRUE becomes FALSE and FALSE as TRUE, multiply with the original matrix to get the output in a `matrix`.  This will also replace the values in 'x' that ends with '0' as 0.  Then negate (`!`) again  so that `0` gets convert to TRUE and all others as FALSE.  Use `which` and we get the index corresponding to TRUE values.

```
which(!x*(!(grepl('0$', x))), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Comment: Could you explain why is it that I have to add the backticks to get ``dim<-`(grepl('0$', x), dim(x))` to yield the right result? I'm not very familiar with their use.

Comment: @dasf I updated the output. Some functions like `dim<-` , `names<-` can be assigned in that way.  Other option would be to explicitly assign as `dim(output) <- dim(x)` (but we have to write one more line).